# Check if a string contains Asterisk (*)

Tags: linux, string, bash, init

I want to check if my string contain one or more asterisk.

I have tried this :

```
if [[ $date_alarm =~ .*\*.* ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

It worked when I launch directly the script, but not if this script is called during shutdown (script installed in run level 0 and 6 via update-rc.d)

Any idea, suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is your init system doesn't use `/bin/bash` as an interpreter, instead it will use `/bin/sh`.

Comment: If William's answer worked, don't forget to click the "Accept answer" button!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always quote strings.

To check if the string $date_alarm contains an asterisk, you can do:

```
if echo x"$date_alarm" | grep '*' > /dev/null; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you replace

```
if [[ $date_alarm =~ .*\*.* ]]
```

with

```
if [[ "$date_alarm" =~ .*\*.* ]]
```

you might also want to try:

```
if [[ "$date_alarm" =~ '\*+' ]]
```

not sure about that one...

regards

Comment: if [[ "$date_alarm" =~ .*\*.* ]]

Don't work, but as I said the strange thing is that it doesn't work only in init context during shutdown 

if [[ "$date_alarm" =~ '\*+' ]]
not tested

Tahnks

Comment: Quote the pattern: if [[ "$date_alarm" =~ ".*\*.*" ]]

Answer (score 1):

```
case "$date_alarm" in
*\**)
  ...
  break
  ;;
*)
  # else part
  ...
  ;;
esac
```

The syntax is, well, /bin/sh, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr "$date_alarm" : ".*\*.*"
```

Comment: a bit of explanation would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if echo $date_alarm|perl -e '$_=<>;exit(!/\*/)'
then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally

```
if echo x"$date_alarm" | grep '*' > /dev/null; then
```

did the trick

Strange thing =~ .**.* doesn't work only in init context during shutdown, but work perfectly if launch in bash context....

Comment: no need to call external program such as grep to do what you want. In bash, the case statement should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

No need to redirect stdout like others do. Use the -q option of grep instead:

if echo x"$date_alarm" | grep -q '*' ; then